# How to make heatmap clickable?

Tags: heatmap, clickable

I have attached my code below which I have been using to try and generate a clickable heatmap. The actual heatmap is generated but I cannot produce a click event.

Here is my code:

```
const centerLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(
  Number(28.555040),
  Number(77.241920)
);
const mapProp = {
  center: centerLocation,
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  clickableIcons: true
};
this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
const location = new google.maps.LatLng(
  Number(28.555040),
  Number(77.241920)
);

for (let i = 0; i < userData.length; i++) {
  this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(+userData[i][1], +userData[i][2]),
    map: this.map,
    icon: this.userimage,
    title: userData[i][0]
  });
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
      infowindow.setContent('<a href="#">' + userData[i][0] + '</a>');
      infowindow.open(this.map, this);
    };
  })(this.marker, i));

}
const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
for (let i = 0; i < eventData.length; i++) {
  this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(+eventData[i][1], +eventData[i][2]),
    map: this.map,
    icon: this.image,
    title: eventData[i][0]
  });


  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-shadowed-variable
  google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
      infowindow.setContent('<a href="#">' + eventData[i][0] + '</a>');
      infowindow.open(this.map, this);
    };
  })(this.marker, i));
}

// console.warn(location);

this.marker.setPosition(location);
this.heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: heatmapData,
  dissipating: true,
  radius: 50
});

this.heatmap.setMap(this.map);

// For heatmap color
const gradient = [
  'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
  'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
  'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
  'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
  'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
  'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
  'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
];
this.heatmap.set('gradient', gradient);
// For heatmap color

this.heatmap.set('opacity', 0.6);
```

Answer (score 0):

If by 'clickable' you mean interactive you may want to look at [complexheatmaps](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ComplexHeatmap.html) which offer that specific utility. The supporting documentation can be [found here](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/index.html). An example of what level of interactivity is possible can be found [on this page](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ComplexHeatmap/inst/doc/s7.interactive.html).

Use one of the following to download the package...

Most Recent (you must use force = TRUE):

```
library(devtools)
install_github("jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap", force = TRUE)
library(ComplexHeatmap)
```

Stable:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("ComplexHeatmap", version = "3.8")
```

Alternatively, you may want to look at using [iheatmapr](https://ropensci.github.io/iheatmapr/index.html), though I know very little about it. As it is designed with interactivity as a forethough it may be of use to you. Here is how it was described in the Journal of Open Source Software.

> There are great tools in R for creating simple interactive heatmaps
>   (Galili 2016, Cheng and Galili (2016)) or creating static complex
>   heatmaps (Gu, Eils, and Schlesner 2016). However, there are no tools
>   facilitating the creation of complex, interactive heatmaps.
>   Theiheatmapr package fills this gap, enabling the creation of highly
>   customizable, interactive, complex heatmaps using the plot library
>   (Sievert et al. 2016). The resulting interactive visualizations can
>   easily be incorporated into reproducible R Markdown reports for sharing
>   with collaborators